# Can I bypass host key checking in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I'm running an Ansible playbook with a subtle hack to work on an arbitrary port forwarded port (so I can use one machine with no direct access to lots of machines).

I've got a pre-task to change the `ansible_port` variable, so then when I start running my real tasks and roles, I get prompted to accept the hostkeys for localhost on some random port.

Because I am naive and don't care about security, I would like ssh to auto-accept and redirect to `/dev/null` (or another file for logging).

Is this possible?

Comment: You can do it through ssh options you pass to the ansible config.

Answer (score 37):

This is typically done by setting the following value in `ansible.cfg`:

```
[defaults]
host_key_checking = False
```

If you don't want to modify `ansible.cfg` you can set an environment variable like so:

```
export ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False
```

Source: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_getting_started.html#host-key-checking

Comment: I am using MacOS and setting host_key_checking=False but I still got "WARNING: POSSIBLE DNS SPOOFING DETECTED!". I fixed this after I realized that I connected to a target host of the same name earlier and then rebuilt it so there was an old key in ./ssh/known_hosts.

Comment: Note tht this does **not** answer the question, even though it might appear to. This will stop prompts to accept new host keys, but it will save each host key for future connections in `known_hosts`. What the question wants is " ssh to auto-accept **and redirect to /dev/null**". The [other answer](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/726/24863) provides the correct solution.

Answer (score 27):

In your `ansible.cfg` file you need to add the following line:

```
ssh_args = -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

You could also add those options in your `~/.ssh/config` on every machine from which you run it something like this:

```
Host *
   StrictHostKeyChecking no
   UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
```

Comment: This should work.  Also, look at the [ansible.cfg](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/ansible/devel/examples/ansible.cfg) file for more settings :)

Comment: +1 for Dawny's addition, because those using Paramiko will need to use ansible.cfg

Comment: Is there an appropriate way to set that inside the playbook?  I've tried `ansible_ssh_common_args` and `ansible_ssh_extra_args` and it doesn't override what I've got in the ansible.cfg.  I've got an ansible.cfg that I use for everything else and would rather just override those parameters for this type of playbook than copy it just to make that change.

Comment: I can't speak to those variables, Peter, but you could put a modified ansible.cfg in the directory with this playbook, and it will take precedence.

Comment: UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null completly break ssh security

Comment: I believe the best option is to use StrictHostKeyChecking no and not to use  UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null, you got a vote up anyway :)

Comment: @mmv-ru That depends on the context . Not everyone uses ssh for the standard "connect to remote machine" scenario. E.g. it's common to use constantly-recycled Vagrant boxes for testing. If you use `StrictHostKeyChecking = no` without `UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null` you will pollute `known_hosts` with useless keys. This creates an attack surface: anyone who gets their hand on one of your Vagrant boxes has a public key which your SSH client will accept from remote hosts. If instead the key is discarded every time, then your soon-to-be-recycled Vagrant box leaves no lasting trace on your system.

Answer (score 3):

There are boolean variables for this that can be set where they're needed (such as in playbooks) so as not to do this globally, which reduces overall security.

```yaml
    var: ansible_host_key_checking
    var: ansible_ssh_host_key_checking
    var: ansible_paramiko_host_key_checking
```

So doing `ansible_ssh_host_key_checking: False` in a playbook should work.

However, I don't believe they'll work until Ansible 2.12.  See [Disabling host key checking via variable doesn't seem to work. #49254](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/49254) for details.

For now, I'd recommend doing this:

```sh
ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False ansible-playbook ...
```

...and not setting this in the global Ansible configuration.  It's a good idea to be explicit when disabling security features so that you're aware of what you're doing.